# Restart MSSQL service on demand

Tags: c#, windows

I need to create a small utility that would restart MSSQL service on demand.

I could pass the `net stop` and `net start` to command line, but this won't be the good solution.

Comment: Have you googled this? [See this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31688/Using-the-ServiceController-in-C-to-stop-and-start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ServiceController` class.